# R function for trimming beginning of a string

Tags: r

Here is a sample of the dataset I am working with.

```
df <- data.frame( precinct = c("01-001", "01-002", "Adv 1 01-001", "Adv 1 01-002"), total = c(100, 102, 4, 6))
```

I need to remove the specific string "Adv 1 " while leaving everything else intact. I considered stringr functions like str_replace() and str_remove() but but I understand it only works on single letters. Is there a function or procedure for performing the trimming?

Comment: *"only works on single letters"*, not true at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gsub()` to substitute the text to empty.

**UPDATE 2: as pointed out by @r2evans:**
If you have multiple patterns of "Adv 1 " in the string and you only wish to replace the one that is at the beginning, use "^Adv 1 " in the codes instead of "Adv 1 " (e.g. `df %>% mutate(precinct = gsub("^Adv 1 ", "", precinct))`).

`^` is a regular expression (regex) that specify the beginning of a string.

Thanks @r2evans for the suggestion!

### Tidyverse

This will not replace your `df` unless you assign the result back to it.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(precinct = gsub("Adv 1 ", "", precinct))
```

**UPDATE: in the comment, @Onyambu suggested me to include the following codes for the `tidyverse` solution. Thanks @Onyambu!**

```
df %>% mutate(precinct = str_remove(precinct, 'Adv 1 '))
```

And

```
df %>% mutate(precinct = str_replace(precinct, 'Adv 1 ', ''))
```

### Base R

This will immediately replace your `df`.

```
df[, 1] <- gsub("Adv 1 ", "", df[, 1])
```

Comment: for tidyverse, use `str_remove(precinct, 'Adv 1 ')` or even `str_replace(precinct, 'Adv 1 ', '')`. Quickly do that edit, and will definitely upvote

Comment: OP stated *"beginning of string"*, it might do better to use the `^` anchor

Comment: I've updated my answer to include all of your suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution :

```
df <- data.frame( precinct = c("01-001", "01-002", "Adv 1 01-001", "Adv 1 01-002"), total = c(100, 102, 4, 6))
df[,1] <- trimws(df[,1], whitespace =  "Adv 1")
```